# Arduino Yun closing Asynch shell command

Tags: bash, arduino

I've noticed that process. close() doesn't  kill my Async process.  This is a problem as it causes my Arduino to crash and perform incorrectly. I want to know if there was a better fix, or if I'm just using close wrong.  I tried manually killing but this didn't seem to work. 
My code is as follows:

```
void airdump()
{
  Serial.print("Dumping \n");
  Process p;
  p.runShellCommandAsynchronously("airodump-ng mon0 -w /root/enum");
  delay(3000);
  p.close();
}
```

Comment: This is no longer an issue, i wasn't correct in the way i tried to manually kill the process before.  Now I have automated this process in a script instead of trying to close it through arduino commands.  In case anyone is interested, I essentially run the killall airodump-ng in the back ground that goes off after a certain amount of time while i run the airodump.  The p.close(), however, is still a concern if anyone can give me insight as to how it tries to close the asynch process I'd greatly appreaciate it